# Storing recorded video URL for saving to library later

Tags: ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application where I recording a video. But when the recording is finished, I can't save the video immediately. I need to show an agreement first. So I try to save the URL i get from the image picker. And save the video to the library later. 
This worked fine in iOS4, but not in iOS5. 
I'm new to iOS and Objective-C so I probably made some totally wrong declaration of the property that is supposed to hold the URL.

This is some of the code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>


@interface Video_recViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {

NSURL *tempMoviePath;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *tempMoviePath;
```

.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

NSURL *moviePath = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
NSLog(@"path from image picker: %@", moviePath);
tempMoviePath = moviePath;
NSLog(@"temp movie path: %@", tempMoviePath);
//
[self performSelector:@selector(showAgree) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}

- (void)userAgreed {
NSLog(@"user agreed");
//NSLog(@"temp movie path: %@", tempMoviePath);
[self saveMyVideo:tempMoviePath];
//[self performSelector:@selector(showSurvey) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void)saveMyVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL {

NSLog(@"saving movie at: %@", videoURL);

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL])
{
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL
                                completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}
     ];
} 
[library release]; 

}
```

Output from log when didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is:

```
temp movie path: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/8CFD1CB7-70A0-465C-B730-817ACE5A4F78/tmp/capture-T0x119660.tmp.hNFzkY/capturedvideo.MOV
```

Output from the log when doing "saveMyVideo". The URL has suddenly turn into this!! :

```
saving movie at: (
"0.31269",
"0.32899",
"0.63999",
"0.33001",
"0.3",
"0.6",
"0.15",
"0.05999"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The wrong code was:

```
tempMoviePath = moviePath;
```

> Because I'm setting a declared property I must use the set & get methods. It should be:

```
[self setTempMoviePath:moviePath];
```

> Apparently iOS 4 wasn't so hard on this, but iOS5 can't handle it. But, anyway, it was wrong writing like that. I admit my mistake. :)